# Efficiency of line by line file reading in Python

Tags: python, performance, file

Right now I am writing some Python code to deal with massive twitter files.  These files are so big that they can't fit into memory.  To work with them, I basically have two choices.

1. I could split the files into smaller files that can fit into memory.
2. I could process the big file line by line so I never need to fit the entire file into memory at once.  I would prefer the latter for ease of implementation.

However, I am wondering if it is faster to read in an entire file to memory and then manipulate it from there.  It seems like it could be slow to constantly be reading a file line by line from disk.  But then again, I do not fully understand how these processes work in Python.  Does anyone know if line by line file reading will cause my code to be slower than if I read the entire file into memory and just manipulate it from there?

Comment: Why not try reading line by line and see? If it works out for you, then it's great, and it's not like changing it from there will be hard.

Comment: it's always going to depend on how massive "massive" is.

Comment: A hopefully useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8717312/416626

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For really fast file reading, have a look at the [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module. This will make the entire file appear as a big chunk of virtual memory, even if it's much larger than your available RAM. If your file is bigger than 3 or 4 gigabytes, then you'll want to be using a 64-bit OS (and 64-bit build of Python).

I've done this for files over 30 GB in size with good results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process the file line by line, you could simply use the file object as an iterator:

```
for line in open('file', 'r'):
    print line
```

This is pretty memory efficient; if you want to work on a batch of lines at a time, you could also use the `readlines()` method of the file object with a *sizehint* parameter. This reads in *sizehint* bytes plus enough number of bytes to complete the last line.